# Find if Duplicates Exist SML NJ

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I want to write a single function that searches a list and finds if there are any duplicates values in this list.  The function should return a boolean.  Here is where I'm at, but this is not working...

```
fun myFunc [] = true
myFunc(x::xs) = 
if(x=myFunc(xs)) then false
else myFunc(xs);

[1,2,2,3,4,5,6] should return true
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] should return false
[1,2,3,4,5,6,1] should return true
```

thanks!

Comment: You realise that SML/NJ supports sets?

Comment: No, I mean that you can use the set to detect whether your list contains duplicates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Marcin said in the comment, an easy and efficient way is to use set for checking duplication. SML/NJ have many set structures available in [Utility Library](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/util-lib-part.html#section:0).

Regarding your function, you cannot compare `x` and `myFunc xs` since they may not have the same type. And empty list is a list without duplication (`myFunc []` should return `false`).

This works:

```
fun duplicated [] = false
  | duplicated (x::xs) = (List.exists (fn y => x = y) xs) orelse (duplicated xs)
```

However, the worst-case time complexity is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* (`n` is the length of the list) which is quite inefficient.

Comment: I actually just figured the problem out and this is exactly what I did.  Thank you!

Comment: Why not a set-based solution, out of interest?

Comment: Sometimes I'm thinking that there should be a penalty tax on writing redundant conditionals like `if ... then true else ...` :)

Comment: @AndreasRossberg: I hope that the penalty is as small as one more edit :).