# Find if Duplicates Exist SML NJ opposite

Tags: sml, smlnj

Regarding to an older question [Find if Duplicates Exist SML NJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033165/find-if-duplicates-exist-sml-nj), if I want the opposite result:

```
[1,2,2,3,4,5,6] should return false
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] should return true
[1,2,3,4,5,6,1] should return false
```

how can I have it with:

```
fun duplicated [] = false
| duplicated (x::xs) = (List.exists (fn y => x = y) xs) orelse (duplicated xs)
```

For example,

```
fun non_duplicated ps =
case ps of
[] => false
| x::xs' => (List.exists (fn y => x<>y) xs') andalso (non_duplicated xs')
```

doesn't work.

Why???
Thanks.

Comment: assume ps is a string list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to obtain the opposite result, just define the function as follows:

```
fun non_duplicated xs = not (duplicated xs)
```

That said, you can push `not` inwards the body of `duplicated` function using [De Morgan laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
not (a orelse b) <=> (not a) andalso (not b)
not exists equal <=> forall (not equal)
not false <=> true
```

Then you arrive at the opposite version:

```
fun non_duplicated [] = true
  | non_duplicated (x::xs) = 
      (List.forall (fn y => x <> y) xs) andalso (non_duplicated xs)
```